# how to store "thing" - "country" relationship in database?

Tags: database, database-design

How to store relationship between "Thing" and "Country"?

- one "Thing" can have one or more "Countries"
- user can mark "Select all countries" for each "Thing"
- user can mark "Select all Europe" (or any other region) for each "Thing"

1)  So is this right to have three tables - "Thing", "Country" and relationship table "Thing_Country" where to store all countries user have selected? I believe this is the right approach, but if user would select very often "all countries" then each time database would be filled in with about more than 100 records, is this ok?

In this case to find out if user have selected "All Europe countries", I have to: first select all europe countries; second select all "things" countries; third compare both lists, right?

3) Another question is about very similar structure, but more complex.

What if we have some other relationship instead of "`Country`". For example, "`Category`" and there are more than 100 (let say 10 000) Categories. What if user selects "all categories", should I also store all 1000 FK's? Or are there any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a collection of information like Country or Category, you design a special database table that refers to itself.

```
Country
-------
Country ID
Parent Country ID
Country Name
...
```

The data for this table would look something like this

```
Country ID     Parent Country ID     Country Name
----------     -----------------     ------------
     0               null            World
     1                 0             Europe
     2                 0             Africa
    ...
     9                 1             Spain
    10                 2             Libya
```

So, when you look up Spain, you can see that the parent country is Europe.  When you look up Europe, the parent country is World.  Since the parent country of World is null, you've gone as far as you can.

You can read through the table and sort by country name, parent country id to get a tree list of the countries

```
   World
   -       Africa
   -       -        Libya
   -       Europe
   -       -        Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you somehow have special values All Countries or Europe? That way your program cuts down on the number of database entries and you can even have special calls if someone selected all countries. So if you select all european countries the program knows to assign that thing the value europe.  I think that should also work for categories. But I am not sure.